# Full text search on view inside a WITH statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have the following problem. When executing the query below, I recieve the following error:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the
>   current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. Msg 0,
>   Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the current
>   command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

```
WITH PagingRows AS 
    ( 
        Select 
            ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By LastName ASC) As Row,AddressBookId 
        FROM 
            AccountView  
        WHERE 
        (
            [AccountView].[AddressBookId] IN 
            (
               SELECT [key] FROM CONTAINSTABLE([AccountView],*,'"searchword*" ')
            )
        )
    ) 
    Select 
        [t0].*
    From
        PagingRows c    
        Inner Join AccountView t0 on c.AddressBookId = t0.AddressBookId 
    Where 
        c.Row Between 0 + 1 AND 0 + 50 
    Order By c.Row Asc FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

The 'AccountView' is a view that is full text indexed. Parts of the query also work  alone.
As the query below does execute without problems.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By LastName ASC) As Row,AddressBookId 
FROM 
    AccountView  
WHERE 
    [AccountView].[AddressBookId] IN (
        SELECT [key] FROM CONTAINSTABLE([AccountView],*,'"searchword*" ')
    )
```

If the 'AccountView' view is replaced by a table the query does work correctly.
I would like to know how to fix this and what the cause of the error is in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hotfix available for this problem: [KB 2421014](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2421014)